# Trying to refresh specific canvas element

Tags: javascript

I'm simply trying to refresh a canvas element.

I've tried doing this

```
function reload(){
var container = document.querySelectorAll('[canvas]');
var content = container.innerHTML;
container.innerHTML= content;
console.log("Refreshed"); //Watches console.
```

}

But it simply doesn't refresh the canvas element? I can use Jquery on the site if it's easier.

Here is the HTML of the canvas element.

```
<canvas width="800" height="500" style="position: absolute; top: 39px; left: 136px; background-color: transparent; z-index: 10;"></canvas>
```

If you can help me find a solution please.

Answer (score 0):

Currently theres a few issues. First, `[canvas]` should be just `canvas`. Second, you are using `querySelectorAll` which returns a `NodeList` of all canvas objects. So either, use that but then loop over it to update all canvases, or change to `querySelector` which returns just one. And I would recommend using an ID in that case.

Also, this might seem silly but are you calling the function? Or just defining it?

Here it is with `querySelectorAll` and `canvas`:

```js
function reload(){
      var canvases = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');
      for(let canvas of canvases) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var content = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.putImageData(ctx,0,0)
        console.log("Refreshed"); //Watches console.
      }
    }
```

```html
<canvas width="800" height="500" style="position: absolute; top: 39px; left: 136px; background-color: transparent; z-index: 10;"></canvas>
```

Comment: :/ still having problem. So my full script basically sends a POST request. Which will draw some strokes on the canvas. I can't see it until I refresh the page. So when I use your script it just logs "refreshed", but it doesn't reload the canvas. Can you take a look at the HTML of the URL? http://colorillo.com/

Comment: Because I see multiple canvas elements. I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @Sparklestheunicorn try the new code. instead of updating the innerHTML is actually captures in image data and redraws it.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the `container` using `querySelector`

```
var container = document.querySelector('canvas');
```

or `querySelectorAll`

```
var container = document.querySelectorAll('canvas')[0];
```

Now, you attempt to refresh the `canvas` by changing its inner HTML to the formerly known HTML value:

```
var content = container.innerHTML;
container.innerHTML= content;
console.log("Refreshed"); //Watches console.
```

if changing the inner HTML of the `canvas` would refresh it, then it is a hacky approach and it should only work according to my opinion if the HTML actually changes. Instead, it would be better to just store the content of the `canvas` somewhere, then clear it:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

and draw it again.

Answer (score -1):

You are wrong in using `document.querySelectorAll()`. Since you are selecting a single target, you should use `document.querySelector()`. Try this.

```
function reload(){
    var container = document.querySelector('canvas');
    var content = container.innerHTML;
    container.innerHTML = content;
    console.log("Refreshed");
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Maybe you can look at the HTML of the URL?

Comment: William, it pays to run/test the code yourself before posting the solution. You were correct that querySelectorAll wouldn't work as they were not then looping over, but the other problem was the selector being used as well.

Comment: @KeeghanMcGarry i'm sorry, it was my bad. thank you for your advice.